# Vigenere cipher while maintaining space and encrypt only words starting with consonent letters [Java]

Tags: java, string, encryption

I'm trying to write a program which will encrypt a sentence using Vigenere cipher, but only the words starting with consonant letters, and while storing spaces.
I'm not very good with Java yet, but I wrote a method which encrypts any given word (all small letters) I had thought using array to print spaces where needed and ignore words starting with vowels would be enough, but doing so is actually giving me wrong output whenver I'm printing the 2nd word or so on of the array. Could someone please guide me what I'm doing wrong? And is there any better way to do this?
Here's my code so far:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner u = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String k = u.next();
    u.nextLine();
    String message = u.nextLine();
    String[] f = message.split(" ");
    System.out.println(encipher(message,k));

    for (String s : f) {
        if (s.charAt(0) == 'a' || s.charAt(0) == 'e' || s.charAt(0) == 'i' ||
                s.charAt(0) == 'o' || s.charAt(0) == 'u') {
            System.out.println(s);
        } else {
            System.out.println(encipher(s, k));
        }

    }
}


public static String encipher(String message, final String key)
{
    String output = "";

    for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < message.length(); x++)
    {
        char c = message.charAt(x);
        if (c < 'a' || c > 'z')
            continue;
        output += (char) ((c + key.charAt(y) - 2 * 'a') % 26 + 'a');
        y = ++y % key.length();
    }

    return output;
}}
```

You can see the difference between the normal output (ignores spaces and vowel/consonant) and the array output. For a string key obi and string message "olimpiada brasileira de informatica" it should print "olimpiada psigjtsjzo em informatica" but in array its printing "olimpiada psigjtsjzo rf informatica" [ignore the printline thing for now on, I'll fix it once I get the encryption right]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When encryption is applied word-by-word, the key is reset for each word and `"de"` is encrypted with `"ob"`:

```
brasileira
obiobiobio

de
ob
```

When entire message is enciphered, the key is NOT reset (`"olimpiada"` has 9 letters which is divisible by `"obi".length() == 3`), and `"de"` is encrypted with `"bi"`:

```
olimpiada brasileira de informatica
obiobiobi obiobiobio bi obiobiobiob
```

So, if may be needed to remember somehow `y` index, or another method should be implemented to provide a character in the non-blank key at the *next* index:

```java
private static Map<String, Integer> keyIndexes = new HashMap<>();

private static char getNextPosition(String key) {
    return key.charAt(keyIndexes.compute(
        key, (k, v) -> v == null ? 0 : (v + 1) % k.length()
    ));
}

private static void resetKey(String key) {
    keyIndexes.remove(key);
}
```

Then the method `encipher` could be updated as:

```
public static String encipher(String message, final String key)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    for (char c : message.toCharArray())
    {
        if (c < 'a' || c > 'z')
            continue; // skip non-letters

        output.append((char) ((c + getNextPosition(key) - 2 * 'a') % 26 + 'a'));
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

Test:

```java
String message = "olimpiada brasileira de informatica";
String k = "obi";
System.out.println(encipher(message, k));
// !!!
resetKey(k);

for (String s : message.split(" ")) {
    if (s.matches("[aeiou]\\w*")) { // use regexp to detect a word starting with a vowel
        System.out.println(s);
    } else {
        System.out.println(encipher(s, k));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
cmqaqqoeipsigjtsjzoemwoncsuouqqb   // full message, spaces skipped
olimpiada
psigjtsjzo
em
informatica
```

---

If it is needed to keep non-letters and the words starting with vowels as is for the entire message (not just a single word), a couple of flags should be added to track if current character is inside a word, and if a first vowel has been detected:

```java
public static String encipherWork(String message, final String key) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    
    boolean inWord = false;
    boolean firstVowel = false;

    for (char c : message.toCharArray()) {
        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
            if (!inWord) {
                firstVowel = (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
                inWord = true;
            }
            if (!firstVowel) {
                output.append((char) ((c + getNextPosition(key) - 2 * 'a') % 26 + 'a'));
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            inWord = false;
            firstVowel = false;
        }
        output.append(c); // print non-enciphered characters
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

Output for this method:

```
olimpiada psigjtsjzo em informatica // full message
olimpiada
psigjtsjzo
em
informatica
```

Comment: thank you soooo much mate!!